# discord.js Running a command sends a duplicate text

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Here is my code, whenever I run the $dm command it runs it but also runs the $help command.
I know its probably a newbie question but if someone could help me out it will be appreciated

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

client.once('ready', () => { client.user.setActivity('Use $help for a list of commands!', { type: "PLAYING" }); });
    console.log('Ready!');
    

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}ping`)) {
        message.channel.send('Pong.');
    } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}beep`)) {
        message.channel.send('Boop.');
    } else if (message.content === `${prefix}server`) {
        message.channel.send(`Server name: ${message.guild.name}\nTotal members: ${message.guild.memberCount}`);
    } else if (message.content === `${prefix}user-info`) {
        message.channel.send(`Your username: ${message.author.username}\nYour ID: ${message.author.id}`);
    console.log(message.content);
    } else if (message.content === (`${prefix}dm`)) {
        message.author.send("string");
    } else if (message.content === "$help") {}
        let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Command List")
        .setDescription("$help, $ping, $beep, $server, $user-info, $dm")
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        message.channel.send(embed)

}

,
)
client.login(token)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`else if (message.content === "$help") {}` <- The issue

You're closing the curly braces too early and so the execution of your code below isn't actually dependant on the if statement.

It should look like this

```
else if (message.content === "$help") {
        let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Command List")
        .setDescription("$help, $ping, $beep, $server, $user-info, $dm")
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        message.channel.send(embed)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must place this code:

```
        let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Command List")
        .setDescription("$help, $ping, $beep, $server, $user-info, $dm")
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        message.channel.send(embed)
```

**within** these curly braces:
    `} else if (message.content === "$help") {}`

Tip: Use switch statements instead